# Yii2 internationalizating slug and controller

Tags: yii2, internationalization, yii2-advanced-app, friendly-url

I'm making a yii2 site in 2 languages (for now) using `yii`'s native `i18n` module, but how can I add multilanguage support for the action URLs?

For instance one of my actions is `category/slug` and in English, it will show as

**`http://example.com/category/chair`**

but in spanish it has to be shown as

**`http://example.com/categoria/silla`**

and so on for other languages shown in the future

right now im manually adding my routes like:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            'marca/<slug>' => 'site/brand',
            'categoria/<slug>' => 'site/category',
            'brand/<slug>' => 'site/brand',
            'category/<slug>' => 'site/category',
        ],
    ],
```

Do i need to manually route every action to its correct controller or is it possible to add a more automated form using `yii::t()` function?

Comment: maybe you need this multilingual [**`component`**](https://github.com/DevGroup-ru/yii2-multilingual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to write your own `UrlRule` class, implementing `yii\web\UrlRuleInterface` and configure your `UrlManager`.

[read more here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

basically it is about "translating" a given request like '`/categoria/silla`' to your internal url `['site/category', 'slug' => $slug, 'lang' => $lang]` in your UrlRule's '`parseRequest`' method. '`createUrl`' is the other way round.